# Select values from a json that are not equal with something in python

Tags: python, json, list

I have the following code

```
import json

x= [{'name': 'a', 'payment': '$10'}, {'name': 'b', 'payment': '$15'}, {'name': 'c', 'payment': '$0'}] 

y = json.dumps(x)
```

I would like to select all the values that don't have the value $0 and print them, like this

```
[{"name": "a", "payment": "$10"}, {"name": "b", "payment": "$15"}]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
x_filtered = [i for i in x if i['payment'] != '$0']
```

You can use a functional approach:

```
x_filtered = list(filter(lambda i: i['payment'] != '$0', x))
```

Or the good ol' fashioned for loop:

```
x_filtered = []
for i in x:
    if i['payment'] != '$0':
        x_filtered.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for d in x:
    if d['payment']=='$0':
        continue
    print(d)
```

if you need them in a list before printing them just create a list beforehand and append the dictionaries to it instead of directly printing them out

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple list comprehension

```
>>> x
[{'name': 'a', 'payment': '$10'}, {'name': 'b', 'payment': '$15'}, {'name': 'c', 'payment': '$0'}]
>>> [y for y in x if y['payment'] != '$0']
[{'name': 'a', 'payment': '$10'}, {'name': 'b', 'payment': '$15'}]
```